# How can I visualize my index.html page using spring rest docs

Tags: kotlin, documentation-generation, spring-restdocs

I am basically starting using spring rest docs to generate the documentation of my rest services. The problem is that I don't know how can I visualize the documentation from my application. I was suposse to see the results in: http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html. But when I open this url I'm seeing the issue: 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 22 22:36:46 COT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

I have used the nex tutorial step by step: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-restdocs/. I was able to follow all the steps and now in my project I have the snippets:

[image]

And also the index.html page was created in the path: target/generated-docs/index.html:

[image]

In my pom.xml I have added the next plugin:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDocumentName>index.adoc</sourceDocumentName>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${project.build.directory}/snippets</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Finally I am runing my application with the next class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = [
            "com.espn.csemobile.espnapp",
            "com.espn.personalization"]
)
open class SportscenterProductApi

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val app = SpringApplication(SportscenterProductApi::class.java)
    app.setBannerMode(Mode.LOG)
    app.setLogStartupInfo(true)
    app.run(*args)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-packaging-the-documentation), you need to configure your build to copy the generated HTML into a location where it'll be packaged in your app.

Add the following plugin configuration to your `pom.xml` after the configuration of the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin> 
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration> 
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                </outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                        </directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This should make the documentation be available at http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html.